# How to format special decimals in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decimal

In a pandas DataFrame column I have numbers like this

```
2840.189941
```

rounded to two decimals:

```
sp.loc['2019-05-13', 'Open'].round(2)
```

​instead of getting `2840.19`, I would like to format the numbers to .25 increments, so that I get this format:

```
2840.25
2840.50
2840.75
...
```

Any Ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need multiple by `4`, use [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html) and divide by `4`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Open': range(284018, 284100, 5)}) / 100

df['new'] = df['Open'].mul(4).round().div(4)
print (df)
       Open      new
0   2840.18  2840.25
1   2840.23  2840.25
2   2840.28  2840.25
3   2840.33  2840.25
4   2840.38  2840.50
5   2840.43  2840.50
6   2840.48  2840.50
7   2840.53  2840.50
8   2840.58  2840.50
9   2840.63  2840.75
10  2840.68  2840.75
11  2840.73  2840.75
12  2840.78  2840.75
13  2840.83  2840.75
14  2840.88  2841.00
15  2840.93  2841.00
16  2840.98  2841.00
```